# Angular 2 em produção

Tags: node.js, angular

Eai galera,tenho uma aplicação em Angular 2 que quero publicar ele no site www.umbler.com servidor de hospedagem mas não consig, tem colocar no servidor em NodeJs mas não funciona. 
Não sei como funciona a parte de build, etc.
Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas vc deve fazer sua aplicação local a depois subir para o servidor. Da mesma forma que usar NPM, Bower, Composer, etc.

Comment: Com angular 2 quando gero o build é criado a pasta /dist onde devo colocar em um servidor tomcat por exemplo, como eu faria isso la?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para colocar em um servidor nodejs:

1- Se você estiver usando angular cli execute o comando para gerar os bundles:

```
ng build --prod
```

Isso irá gerar a pasta dist com todo o código estatico do site.

2- [Baixe o Node js em sua máquina de desenvolvimento](https://nodejs.org/en/)

3- Após instalar digite no prompt (no diretório um nível acima da pasta dist):

```
npm init
```

Responda as perguntas do console (deixando o script de inicialização como index.js)

4- Crie um arquivo index.js:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();


app.set('port', 80);


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));


app.get('*',function (req, res) {

  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');

});


app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {

  console.log('Running on port ', app.get('port'));

});
```

Sua estrutura de diretório deve ficar:

```
home
    -dist/
      --arquivos html
    -index.js
    -package.json
```

Para testar local execute:

```
npm start
```

---

**Para executar um site em cada rota:**

Considerando que haverão dois diretórios dist: dist_site1 e dist_site2

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();


app.set('port', 80);

// Servir estático os dois dists em rotas separadas:
app.use('/site1',express.static(__dirname + '/dist_site1/'));
app.use('/site2',express.static(__dirname + '/dist_site2/'));

// Direcionar para um dos sites caso entre com o link do dominio
app.get('/',function (req, res) {

  res.redirect('/site1');

});

// Direcionar todas as rotas não interceptadas pelo estático para o angular
app.get('/site1/*',function (req, res) {

  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist_site1/index.html');

});

// Direcionar todas as rotas não interceptadas pelo estático para o angular
app.get('/site2/*',function (req, res) {

  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist_site2/index.html');

});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {

  console.log('Running on port ', app.get('port'));

});
```

Comment: Isso funcionou, obrigado, mas apenas para uma aplicacao, tentei fazer o node gerenciar 2 aplicacoes enviando cada uma atraves do path, mas nesse caso nao da certo, sabe me dizer como resolver?

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo no descritivo da solução com os comentários em cada linha chave.